# How do you get a printer's IP in lion?

Tags: macos, printing, network

How did you find out an existing printer's IP in lion?

In Snow Leopard you can do it in this way:

1. Open System Preferences
2. Select the printer that you want to find the IP for
3. Click 'Options & Supplies'
4. The IP is shown next to the 'URL:' label, and might say 'lpd://192.168.0.50/'

How can you do this in OS X Lion?

Comment: How can you "change" the IP address on an existing printer without starting over and adding the printer again. I am having an issue with and HP7310xi, I use to have the scan feature show in the print & scan preferences menu but now I can get an Added printer to show the scan icon next to the printer icon.

Comment: if its connected to the network, you should be able to see it on your home network overview, say on your router?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use the built-in CUPS web interface to get detailed printer information:

http://localhost:631/printers/

On newer versions of macOS you'll need to run the following command to enable the web interface:

```
cupsctl WebInterface=yes
```

Comment: genius... I had no idea that existed!

Comment: +1. It boggles my mind why they'd hide it in a web interface...

Comment: To log-in, you've to use the same credentials which you're using for the administrator account.

Comment: It's disabled by default, but if you're comfortable with text files you can always "sudo less /private/etc/cups/printers.conf" and get at everything.

Comment: Web Interface is Disabled

The web interface is currently disabled. Run "cupsctl WebInterface=yes" to enable it.

It is a lan of printers..

Comment: This doesn't seem to show an IP address if the device is connected through Bonjour.