# How do I get the actual ip address of a printer in OSX Yosemite

Tags: macos, printing, cups

I need to know the ip address of my printer from OSX to be able to configure it in my daughters Windows laptop. I tried the solution suggested in [How do you get a printer's IP in lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30149/how-do-you-get-a-printers-ip-in-lion) but I only get: *dnssd://AL-CX11-08F61E._printer._tcp.local./auto*, and I cannot ping AL-CX11-08F61E._printer._tcp.local. because it does not resolve. Still, I can print. How do I get the actual IP address?

Edit: why doesn't it resolve from the commandline, but still OSX can print?

Comment: Is the printer actually on the network, or is it connected directly to your Mac?

Comment: The printer is on the network, not directly connected.

Comment: Is the IP address of your printer defined manually or through DHCP?
If its IP address is dynamically attributed through DHCP, you won't have a stable configuration on Windows if you use an IP address. The correct method starts by defining a name and a static IP address to your printer on your router (ex.: `snow-white  192.168.1.128`). Then you will be able to configure it from MacOS X and Windows with its network name (ex.: `snow-white.local`).

Comment: Please clarify your comment n°2: how is your printer accessing the network? Add this info at the beginning of your question: this is a key detail.

Comment: Is it awake? Mine doesn't respond to arp or nmap if it's asleep, though it will wake & print if it's an already-known device for that machine.

Comment: so you do not actually want to know the IP, you want to know how to get it within the OS X.

Comment: The printer is likely added in via Bonjour/policy, which would use a different name than the IP. Try the following: 1) Launch Network Utility (can be accessed via Spotlight, magnifying glass in upper-right or Space+Command). 2) Go to Lookup in NU. 3) Enter the following address: AL-CX11-08F61E.local 4) Click Lookup and see if you receive a response. If this works, I'll post it as an answer below. The system does an IP lookup based on the printers' name across the network and should return its IP.

Comment: @smoooosher: I accepted the answer given by Kent, but your answer also provided valuable information: the fact that you can ping the printer by removing _printer._tcp from the hostname. Thank you for that.

Comment: I don't know why my question was downvoted? It did show research effort, and how my printer is accessing the network was implied in the question. Why would I need to find the ip address if it is directly connected?

Comment: You should be able to *"ping AL-CX11-08F61E.local."* (**not**  *"ping AL-CX11-08F61E._printer._tcp.local."* !)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a tool [Bonjour Browser](http://www.tildesoft.com/) which will show you the connected devices on the current network.  The connection types are sorted, and you can usually find the printers in **Print Spooler (_printer._tcp.)** or **Internet Printing Protocol (_ipp._tcp.)** sections.  Each device will list its IP address, among other information.

Comment: Thanks. This tool indeed shows the ip address as well as other useful info.

Comment: This tool is now called "Discovery" and is available in the Mac app store. Also, as of today, there is a link to the Mac app store page on the website provided in this answer.

Comment: Bonjour Browser does not run on macOS versions newer than Mojave.

Answer (score 42):

Use http://localhost:631/printers/ to see the list of printers available. The page shows both printer model and its IP/name under the Printers tab.
To enable the cups page, run `cupsctl WebInterface=yes` in terminal.

If it does not directly show an IP address, click on the printer, where usually there is a connection entry like in this example:

[image: Example entry for an auto-detected OKI MC342 printer]

Afterwards run `cupsctl WebInterface=no` in the terminal.

If the above still does not resolve to an IP-address, then try `dns-sd` as explained in [How can I list the IP addresses of all the AirPrint printers on a network?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175241/how-can-i-list-the-ip-addresses-of-all-the-airprint-printers-on-a-network); search for "_ipp._tcp" in that post.

For that to work you MUST be on the same network as the printer: it does not work if you are on a different network (for instance when on the road and the discovered printer is at home).

Example of a printer not showing the IP address:

[image]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer... no cruft to install, simple to use.

Comment: This does not show the IP for my printer. The column `Location` is empty :-(

Comment: @alpipego My Location is a user entered field to show where the printer is physically located. I don't think you'll see an ip address there.

Comment: @alpipego click on a printer; most printer drivers will show a "Connection" that in one form or the other has an IP address for the printer. I'll add a screenshot to the answer.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175241/how-can-i-list-the-ip-addresses-of-all-the-airprint-printers-on-a-network really helped me figure it out, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Open the Terminal application in Applications/Utilities

type

```
lpstat -s
```

Followed by pressing return. You should see a list of all your installed printers. In a common setup, printers have been setup using the [Line Printer Daemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_Printer_Daemon_protocol) protocol. If that's the case where you are, the number after lpd:// is the IP address.

Unless you are using a print server, in which case you’ll see the print server’s fully qualified domain name there.

Comment: This is not necessarily true. What if the printer's connection does not use the LPD (Line Printer Daemon) protocol, but IPP (Internet Printing Protocol) instead? Or DNSSD *("dnssd://...)"* or AppSocket *("socket://...")*? And then, during setup of the queue not the IP address was used, but the hostname??

Comment: Would you like me to edit my answer?

Answer (score 4):

All modern networkable printers (which have a display) have an option to set and display the IP address. Often times you hold the "go button" down for 15 seconds, or while powering up the printer. Sometimes you need a utility that goes with the printer to set and/or view it. Check your manual or find one online.

Comment: This is correct, but does not answer the question. I want to get it from OSX, not from the printer.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to

```
 ping -c 1  AL-CX11-08F61E.local. | grep PING
```

(***NOT*** `ping AL-CX11-08F61E._printer._tcp.local.`).

The line you see then should reveal the IP address of the printer.